# Replacing strings in html with array content in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, arrays, replace

For a little experiment, I was curious if it possible to replace strings like the ones below with content from an array, one after the other. Take a snippet like this for example:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>$$Insert text here$$</h1>
<div>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<div>$$Insert text here$$</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="$$Insert text here$$"><br>
    <p>Here some other text</p>
</div>
```

The string "$$Insert text here$$" would always be the same, I would like to replace each of them in a linear fashion with the content of an array such as:

```
var replacements=["This is a headline","I am a text","I am yet another text"];
```

Would this be possible in a simple way without the need to tame a templating engine? (Nothing against temp again, just curious)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here's one way to do it:

```
var replacements=["This is a headline","I am a text","I am yet another text"],
    i = 0;
$("body").html(function(j, html) {
    return html.replace(/\$\$Insert text here\$\$/g,function() {
        return replacements[i++];
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d6D68/

Note that if the `$$Insert text here$$` text appears more times than there are replacement values the leftover ones will be set to "undefined".

I don't really *recommend* doing a text replace on the whole body, because (amongst other reasons) it would remove any event handlers, etc., but perhaps this will at least give you some ideas. (And it is an easy way to cope with replacement text both between element tags and in attributes.)

Comment: I would assume the replacement is done before first insertion, thus removing event handlers is not not an issue

Comment: I think you have over-complicated the whole thing.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - I think my answer is less complicated than yours. I have _one_ call to `.html()`, and _one_ call to `.replace()`. The anonymous function passed to `.replace()` is the only one that will be invoked more than once. You have used `.each()` and then on each iteration called `.html()` _twice_ and `.replace()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn - After taking a close look it does seem to be a smart use of `replace` :)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - Thanks. Of course the advantage to your method is that you stop when you run out of list items, whereas my code happily carries on inserting "undefined", but then for this type of functionality the list would have to be carefully crafted to match up to the `$$..$$` template text in the html (because otherwise the individual replacements would be nonsensical), so it shouldn't be a problem either way.

Comment: @nnnnnn you can fix the carrying on easily by doing `||arguments[0]`

Comment: @JanDvorak - Indeed, thanks for the suggestion. But as I mentioned (when I edited my last comment) the items in the replacement list seem so specific (e.g., "This is a headline") that I would expect the list to be carefully matched up to the html. (It would be different if the `$$..$$` "template" thingies were individually associated with specific list items.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = ["button", "textarea"], opt = $("body").html();
$.each(list, function(i){
    opt = opt.replace(/\$\$insert\$\$/, list[i]);
});
$("body").html(opt);
```

Basically you just have to replace them one by one. No need to create anonymous functions inside `replace` and make it so complicated with templating engine.

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/m3sPw/

Note: This should be done before attaching any EventListeners.
<sub>Note2: This code only demonstrates the barely minimum to make it work as the question stated. Escape all malicious characters before inserting text into DOM to prevent double replacement.</sub>

Comment: as nnnnnn said, it's a bad idea to do a search&replace on the entire document.body.innerHTML, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: also, jQuery docs recommend against wrapping plain arrays in jQuery. If you must use jQuery for looping, do `$.each`

Comment: @JanDvorak - EventListeners will not be an issues if all events are attached afterward.

Comment: Also, you're doing `$("body")` and `$("body").html(...)` _many_ times. If you have six things to replace, this will parse the document six times, and serialise it six times. This is a Bad Thing^(c) for performance

Comment: @JanDvorak - Yes it would, but however considering today's computer performance it wouldn't be a problem unless you have a couple thousands of them to replace, which is a bad practice anyway.

Comment: Uhh... he's not creating _functions_ inside replace. He's creating one function, that is called multiple times. You're doing the same.

Comment: You fixed `$("body")`, but you still restart the regex at the beginning for each replace. This reduces performance (a lot), but it also creates issues with double replacement. Say, one of the texts to replace contains `$$insert$$` as well.

Comment: @JanDvorak - OK I get the point that it is not extremely efficient, but this is only a sample code to OP's question which of course he will have to tweak it before applying it. And this will be my final editing.

Comment: My answer is correct and working and yet it is downvoted without explanation. Ahh the spirit of StackOverflow...

Comment: I have given my explanation. Your code is inefficient and susceptible to double replacement.

Comment: @TusharGupta no, it's not. see my comment (and the whole thread, for that matter)

Comment: @TusharGupta do you consider susceptibility to double replacement a non-issue?

Comment: @JanDvorak - First, inefficient does not mean it is wrong. Second, the saying that double replacement will occur is similar to saying adding `<!--` will break the whole page.

Comment: I wouldn't be afraid to say that searching in a large string (like, 160 kchar long - the size of this page) redundantly multiple times is going to have a perceptible impact on performance and is a reason enough to not upvote. And double replacement _is_ a problem if part of the content comes from the user. Even if you escape all parameters the same way (and thus prevent script injection), you still end up with a broken page.

Comment: ... unless you decide to HTML-escape dollar signs in _every_ parameter, of course. I'm pretty sure `htmlspecialchars` doesn't do that, and I don't think `htmlentities` does that either. Also, you can't html-escape dollars if you want to insert into javascript. You'd need to escape dollars manually after (or before) JSON encoding.

Comment: @JanDvorak - For a page this long it only takes 4ms to process, which is barely noticeable. As the page gets longer the time sure will increase, but it only takes double the time to process which is still [7ms](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/yu4Sr/). To create a extremely noticeable lag, either one will have to insert several thousands of items or the document to be extremely long.

Comment: You're still assuming desktop ;-) This will be very noticeable on non-high-end mobile phones. But performance isn't why I downvoted.

Comment: @JanDvorak - I know that if one insert `$$insert$$` that it will break the code, but it would actually be silly to do that in real scenarios. If user inputs are a concern, then he shouldn't use this method in the first place imo.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 code injection - n. The act of inserting silly strings in order to deliberately break someone's application and to cause it to run your code.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Yes, that's why I'm saying he shouldn't use this method for that kind of purpose, or he will have to remove any malicious character before inserting.

Comment: What kind of purpose do you think it will be used for? You didn't even mention the risk in the answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Well since he mentioned it is just a little experiment, I assumed that security will not be a thing to be keep in mind. Anyway, I just provided him one suggestion of how to achieve it, and it does works.

Comment: @TusharGupta I have lifted my downvote. Now you can lift your upvote you gave in compensation ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak - Thanks for lifting the downvote. I actually agree that security is an important thing to keep in mind when it comes to inserting string, but I believe we should left this to the programmer himself to decide how to do that since it is something that is outside of this question. Anyway, I agree with your arguments though.